# add or delete button to create instances of the same form in ajax

Tags: ajax

I have a 3 tables in a web page which makes asychronous request to a server using ajax. How to add a button '+' or '-' at the top which can add (create same tables) or delete those tables(all the 3 tables together) and multiple same requests can be done???

Comment: You must narrow down your question to: how to create new tables or forms OR you may wanna know to post data using ajax or how to create new html entities using jquery or javascript. Right now you are not providing enough information/code.

Comment: I already have set of tables in the web page.... i need to know how you add same set of tables to the same web page upon clicking the 'add' button so that when you submit them,2 different requests are sent to the server.